# How can I copy an image from a stackPane and then add it to another stackpane?

Tags: javafx, clipboard

I need to copy an image from a stackPane and then need to add that particular image to another stackpane with help of ClipBoard.

Answer (score 1):

You can do it with SnapshotParameters and with a ImageView:

```
...
SnapshotParameters snapParams = new SnapshotParameters();
snapParams.setFill(Color.RED); // see documentation
// with your describtion YOURNODE is your stackpane...
imageview.setImage(YOURNODE.snapshot(snapParams, null));
```

Now you can add imageview to the other stackpane with:

```
otherStackpane.getChildren().add(imageview);
```